# $z^4 = w$ has one solution $z = x + yi$ how do I find the other 3 solutions

Tags: complex-numbers

As the title states,
$z^4 = w$ has one solution $z = x + yi$ how do I find the other 3 solutions

$x,y$ are real numbers

Comment: What about $-z$?

Comment: z is complex @abiessu

Comment: should I make it that $z^4 - w = 0$ then factor difference of  squares to get $(z^2 - \sqrt{w})(z^2 + \sqrt{w})$

Comment: Hint: Write the equation out in polar form and 'solve'. This gives you a relationship between the arguments of the four solutions, which you can use, along with the fact that $x+iy$ is a solution, to write out the other 3.

Comment: Except in the case $w=0$, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are solutions iff $(z_1/z_2)^4=1$. You know how to solve $z^4=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yea z isnt 0 forgot to mention

Comment: @stochasticboy321 hi so I converted $z^4 = w$ into polar form. 

So I just got it with nth roots theorem $\sqrt{4}(1) \sqrt{4}(i) \sqrt{4}(-1) \sqrt{4}(-i) $ how do I connect it to $x+yi$ which one is it

Comment: The difference of squares is one good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to polar coordinates $x + yi = \rho e^{i\phi}$, and using De Moivre's formula,
$$ \sqrt[4]{w} = \rho e^{i\phi + i\pi k/ 2} = \rho e^{i\pi} e^{i\pi k/2}, \quad k \in [0..3]
$$
so multiplying your number by $e^{i\pi/2} = i, e^{i\pi} = -1, e^{i3\pi/2} = -i$ yields the other solutions.

Graphical solution:
[image: Complex graph]

Answer (score 2):

If $z$ and $z'$ are two solutions of $z^4=w$, what is $z/z'$? Can you see that this must be a fourth root of unity? Multiply $x+iy$ by $i$, $-1$, and $-i$ and you’ll get the other three roots. No necessity of ringing in DeMoivre.